# Oracle SQL Developer - CASE Statement to return multiple rows for an ID if conditions met

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a issue with a CASE statement where I'm checking two fields called the primary_code and or the secondary_code.  One or the other will always be populated, but sometime both will be and here lies the problem.  When both fields are populated I need the results to show 2 rows for the case ID.  One with a 1 and the other with a 2.  See below for more details.

```
SELECT CASE_ID,
       CASE WHEN PRIMARY_CODE IS NOT NULL AND SECONDARY_CODE IS NULL THEN 1
            WHEN SECONDARY_CODE IS NOT NULL AND PRIMARY_CODE IS NULL THEN 2
       END AS XP_CODE
FROM TABLE1
```

when conditions are met:

```
CASE_ID   XP_CODE    
5555555   1    
7777777   2
```

But if both fields are not null for any given case_id, then I need the result set to show two rows for the record, one with a value of 1 and the other with the value of 2.

when both primary and secondary code fields are populated results should look like:

```
CASE_ID   XP_CODE
5555555   1
5555555   2
7777777   2
```

there needs to be two records for case id 5555555 since both primary and secondary fields are not null.  Does anyone know how this should be done in Oracle SQL developer tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `case`, you need a join or union all.  I suspect you want:

```
select case_id, 1 as XP_CODE
from table1
where  PRIMARY_CODE IS NOT NULL
union all
select case_id, 2 as XP_CODE
from table1
where SECONDARY_CODE IS NOT NULL;
```